# How can I call derived class non virtual member function using base class pointer without typecasting and using polymorphism?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any possible way that I can make ptr->fun2() possible?

```
 class A
    {
        void fun1()
        {
             A* ptr;
             ptr->fun2();
         }
    }

    class B : class A
    {
        void fun2()
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can make a `virtual` `fun2`?

Comment: @Biffen If you *know* it, you can `static_cast` it. `dynamic_cast` is for when you don't know, or for complicated inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: @Angew Yes, of course. My bad.

Comment: I don't want to cast the base pointer in any way. I don't want to make fun2() virtual either as only one of the many derived classes of base will be implementing it.

Comment: @Anu This goes against so many things. It smells like an XY problem. What is it that you *really* want to do?

Comment: I just want to know if there is any solution to my problem i.e., using namespaces or patterns or some concepts and achieve it

Comment: If you don't want to cast to it, and you not all of the derived classes are going to implement it, what do you propose happen when you call `Fun2()` on `A` and it doesn't exist on the `B` that's currently being pointed to?

Answer (score 5):

That is not possible. C++ is a statically typed language. The type of `ptr` is pointer to `A`. `fun2` is not a member of `A`. By definition, it is impossible to call `fun2` through a pointer/reference to type `A`.

This is normally solved by casting. Since you've disqualified that for unspecified reasons, there is no way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

No. `A` does not have a member function `fun2`, so you may not call `ptr->fun2()` through a pointer of type `A*`.

**If** the pointer happens to point to a derived object that does have such member function, then you may `static_cast` the pointer to the type that does have the member function. If you don't know, then you can attempt to `dynamic_cast` (but only if the type is polymorphic), but that's usually a bad design (but sometimes OK) and not what you want to do.

> I just want to know if there is any solution to my problem

If you want to call `fun2` with a pointer to `A`, then the solution is to add a member function `fun2` to the class `A`. If you want the call to `ptr->fun2` to be dispatched to `B::fun2`, then you'll want to make the function virtual - but for some reason you explicitly don't want to use the tool that was designed for this problem.

> I don't want to make fun2() virtual either as only one of the many derived classes of base will be implementing it.

That doesn't prevent you from having a virtual function in `A`, but it can arguably be bad for the interface to have a virtual function that's used by only one derived class.

What I suggest is to not use `A*` pointer, but a `B*` in the first place. Then you don't need to cast, nor call a virtual function.

> t there is a typecheck happening whether ptr is pointing to object of type B and then "ptr->fun2()" is made in fun1()

Casting might be not such a bad option then. But I have another suggestion: Separate `fun1` into two versions. One that is called for the type `B` where `fun2` is called, and one for other types.

Comment: If you *know* the object is of the correct target type, you can even `static_cast`. Not to mention the fact that `dynamic_cast` requires at least one virtual function in the class.

Comment: I cannot make it virtual as fun2() is not meant for other classes also derived from the same base class and base class also need not implement it.

Comment: @Anu then just dont implement it in the other derived classes, I dont see the problem...

Comment: @user2079303, A* is necessary as the fun1() has other code that requires the pointer to be of base type so that other virtual functions work as expected for whatever object ptr holds.

Comment: @Anu How does a `B*` prevent other virtual functions from working as expected?

Comment: @user2079303, suppose there's a function fun3() declared virtual in class A   and implemented fully in it's derived classes B & C. Then there's this line " ptr->fun3()" somewhere in fun1(). This will not work if we change ptr to B* type.

Comment: @Anu go on, how does using a `B*` prevent `fun3` from working as expected?

Comment: @user2079303 , Because B* ptr cannot point to object of type C which needs some work to do around in base class A.

Comment: @Anu but if you need to call `ptr->fun2`, then `ptr` cannot point to an object of type `C` anyway.

Comment: @user2079303 , sorry, I should have told you that there is a typecheck happening whether ptr is pointing to object of type B and then "ptr->fun2()" is made in  fun1() .

Comment: @Anu OK, if there is a type check already, what on Earth is preventing you from writing a simple `static_cast`? Based on your inheritance hierarchy structure, it will either have no runtime cost, or still cost much less than any type check you may be doing.

Comment: @Angew, my sole purpose is to remove that static cast which is already there.. because base class should not have any idea about its derived class.. not even the names of them which we use while we cast. And im not allowed to use virtual functions either as fun2() is specific only to that derived class

Comment: @Anu if the base class should not have any idea bout its dreived class, then it should not call a function of it's derived class. As I've already answered, using a virtual function is still an option. But it's impossible to say which option is best for you without any information about your problem.

Comment: @Anu "because base class should not have any idea about its derived class" - then it should have no idea about a function named `fun2` existing in a derived class, much less attempt to call it. You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: @Angew, yea.. i agree.. im stuck in such a loop. I just wanted to know if there is any way of doing it either using any new concepts.I just have to remove the cast without using virtual functions. I pity myself!